# How to use Firebase Auth REST API using Google Apps Script?

Tags: firebase, google-apps-script, firebase-authentication

I am trying to sign up users on Firebase Auth using Google Apps Script via the Firebase Auth REST API.

My code looks this.

```
  var apiKey = "XXXX";
  var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/signupNewUser?key=" + apiKey;
   var options = {
     method: 'post',
     contentType: 'application/json',
     email: "email@gmail.com",
     password: "12345678",
     returnSecureToken: true
  }; 
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
```

I am receving the following error.

```
 {
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "ADMIN_ONLY_OPERATION",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "ADMIN_ONLY_OPERATION",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "invalid"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

How do I go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Request body payload should be sent as a 'payload' property of the **options** object.

```
var payload = {
  email: "sauravo14@gmail.com",
  password: 12345678,
  returnSecureToken: true

};

 var options = {
     method: 'post',
     contentType: 'application/json',
     payload: JSON.stringify(payload)
  };
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank You!!

Comment: @user2176475 Good to hear it helped. Could you please mark the question as resolved?